# Pandas cumulative countif (based on condition)

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, countif, cumsum

I have a DataFrame `df` and I am trying to calculate a cumulative count based on the condition that the date in the column `at` is bigger or equal to the dates in the column `recovery_date`.

Here is the original `df`:

```
    at  recovery_date   
0   2020-02-01  2020-03-02
1   2020-03-01  2020-03-31
2   2020-04-01  2020-05-01
3   2020-05-01  2020-05-31
4   2020-06-01  2020-07-01
```

Here is the desired outcome:

```
    at  recovery_date   result
0   2020-02-01  2020-03-02  0
1   2020-03-01  2020-03-31  0
2   2020-04-01  2020-05-01  2
3   2020-05-01  2020-05-31  3
4   2020-06-01  2020-07-01  4
```

The interpretation is that for each `at` there are x amount of `recovery_date`s preceding it or on the same day.

I am trying to avoid using a for loop as I am implementing this for a time-sensitive application.

This is a solution I was able to find, however I am looking for something more performant:

```
def how_many(at: pd.Timestamp, recoveries: pd.Series) -> int:
    return (at >= recoveries).sum()
```

```
df["result"] = [how_many(row["at"], df["recovery_date"][:idx]) for idx, row in df.iterrows()]
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Your example seems incorrect, all `recovery_date` are greater than `at`, which doesn't match you output

Comment: @mozway. I think OP forgot to say if the current `at` greater equals than the previous `recovery_date` because it matches the output. I'm wrong?

Comment: Very possibly. OP should edit the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```py
df['result'] = df['at'].apply(lambda at: (at >= df['recovery_date']).sum())
```

What this does is: For each value in the `at` column, check if there are any `recovery_date`s that are bigger or equal (at this point we have an array of True (=1) and False (=0) values) then sum them.

This yields your desired output

```
          at recovery_date  count  result
0 2020-02-01    2020-03-02      1       0
1 2020-03-01    2020-03-31      1       0
2 2020-04-01    2020-05-01      1       2
3 2020-05-01    2020-05-31      1       3
4 2020-06-01    2020-07-01      1       4
```